# Can Rn -> Rn transformation be one to one but not onto? And vice versa

Tags: linear-algebra

In a transformation into the same space $\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$, can said transformation be one-to-one but NOT onto? And can a transformation be onto but NOT one to one?

What would an example be of both, or is it impossible? I feel like you need to be transforming into a different vector space to accomplish both cases.

Comment: Do you mean a linear map $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$. Or any function?

Comment: I do mean linear map, I wasn't sure how to communicate that properly

Comment: In which case, Omnom has tastily answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible for a (linear) transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$; see the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

In order to get an example of a linear transformation from a space to itself that is one to one but not onto (or vice versa), you would need an infinite-dimensional vector space.  As an example of each, consider differentiation/integration over the space of polynomials.